# I am newbie in Android Studio. I have a task how to display the name automatically when the id / nik field is filled based on data from the database

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit

At this time I'm having trouble writing java code. The concept in this program is when I fill in the NIK field and press the get button, the name (FIELD NAME) will appear automatically based on the data from database

Database Structure

| NIK | NAMA |
| --- | --- |
| 96296 | Farrasta |
| 94878 | Alfian |

[Application View]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/x06Vy.png)

Error when i click get button

```
java.lang.illegalStateException : Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Get Button

```
btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        NikKry = etNik.getText().toString();
        getNama();
    }
});
private void getNama(){
    APIRequestData armNama = RetroMaster.konekRetrofit().create(APIRequestData.class);
    Call<DataMaster> tampilNama = armNama.ardGetNama(NikKry);

    tampilNama.enqueue(new Callback<DataMaster>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DataMaster> call, Response<DataMaster> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                etNama.setText(response.body().getNAMA());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DataMaster> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(TambahActivity.this, "Gagal "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Data Master

```
package com.example.crudoracle.Model;
public class DataMaster {
    private String NIK;
    private String NAMA;
    
    public String getNIK() {

        return NIK;
    }
    public void setNIK(String NIK) {

        this.NIK = NIK;
    }
    public String getNAMA() {

        return NAMA;
    }
    public void setNAMA(String NAMA) {

        this.NAMA = NAMA;
    }
}
```

API request

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("getnama.php")
Call<DataMaster> ardGetNama(
        @Field("NIK") String NIK
);
```

Php file

```
<?php
include ("koneksi.php");
    $NIK = $_POST['NIK'];
    $query = "SELECT NAMA FROM MASTER_KRY WHERE NIK = '$NIK'";
    $eksekusi = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    $cek = oci_execute($eksekusi);
        $response = array();
        while($ambil = oci_fetch_object($eksekusi)){
            $F["NAMA"] = $ambil->NAMA;
            array_push($response, $F);
        }
echo json_encode($response);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Postman response

```
[{"NAMA":"Alfian U"}]
```

Comment: Your response json contains array which doesn't match your data object class so please make sure that you have created correct data class. Or else try removing array from your json response and just make that to be json object

Comment: Hi bro thanks for your advice. But, would u show me how to do that ? or could u send me a reference to solve my problem ? cauze i get stuck right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this change in your data class :

```
    package com.example.crudoracle.Model;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class DataMaster {

@SerializedName("NAMA")
@Expose
private String nama;

public String getNama() {
return nama;
}

public void setNama(String nama) {
this.nama = nama;
}

}
```

Also make this changes in onClick of Get button :

```
btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        NikKry = etNik.getText().toString();
        getNama();
    }
});
private void getNama(){
    APIRequestData armNama = RetroMaster.konekRetrofit().create(APIRequestData.class);
    Call<DataMaster> tampilNama = armNama.ardGetNama(NikKry);

    tampilNama.enqueue(new Callback<List<DataMaster>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<DataMaster>> call, Response<List<DataMaster>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                etNama.setText(response.body()[0].getNAMA());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<DataMaster>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(TambahActivity.this, "Gagal "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

---

Also make change in this :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("getnama.php")
Call<List<DataMaster>> ardGetNama(
        @Field("NIK") String NIK
);
```

Comment: thanks bro, you so good, but i'm sorry, I still confused how to implement "@SerializedName("NAMA" ) var NAMA : String? = null" in DataMaster class and I use java programming language. when i copy that part to DataMaster class i get some error, Would u teach me how to write that properly ?

Comment: Check now I have update the data model class. Try to replace that and then let me know what error you are getting.

Comment: is it true when i implement "@SerializedName("NAMA" ) var NAMA : String? = null
" at DataMaster class under "Private String NIK" ?

Comment: NIK is not required, In your data model you need to have mapped variable for key from your json.

Comment: i get some error "error: array required, but DataMaster found"  at "etNama.setText(response.body()[0].getNAMA());"

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving the array in the API response or not?

Comment: "Receiving array in the API response" is it same when i try at postman and it work properly ?

Comment: postman response when i input NIK field based on database = [{"NAMA":"Alfian U"}]

Comment: Please check now I have added another change in my answer which would solve the issue. @FarrastaKS

Comment: thanks for your help bro, i modified to "                    etNama.setText(response.body().get(0).getNAMA());
" and it work

Comment: No worries also give upvote to this answer so that it can help others as well.